# VC linker error - CVT1100 duplicate resource. type:MESSAGETABLE

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors, embedded-resource

I have been given a very old project with a series of DLLs and drivers which has not been built since 2012.  I'm trying to bring it back to life but as a driver guy I'm really struggling with some of this user mode resource stuff.

I get the following error -

```
CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:MESSAGETABLE, name:1, language:0x0409
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

The project has 1 .rc file which defines 3 icons and a VS_VERSION_INFO and it has one .mc file which has some messages.  If I get rid of the .rc and just build it with the .mc I see the following two resources in the resulting binary:

```
--type=11 --name=1 --language=1033 [type=messagelist offset=0x1ee0a0 size=1452]
--type=24 --name=2 --language=1033 [offset=0x1ee650 size=381]
```

If I get rid of the .mc and just build it with the .rc then I see these resources:

```
--type=3 --name=1 --language=1033 [type=icon offset=0x1ee4f0 size=744]
--type=3 --name=2 --language=1033 [type=icon offset=0x1ee7f0 size=744]
--type=3 --name=3 --language=1033 [type=icon offset=0x1eeaf0 size=744]
--type=14 --name=101 --language=1033 [type=group_icon offset=0x1ee7d8 size=20]
--type=14 --name=102 --language=1033 [type=group_icon offset=0x1eead8 size=20]
--type=14 --name=103 --language=1033 [type=group_icon offset=0x1eedd8 size=20]
--type=16 --name=1 --language=1033 [type=version offset=0x1ee1f0 size=768]
--type=24 --name=2 --language=1033 [offset=0x1eedf0 size=381]
```

But if I try to include both I get the error.  I don't understand what the conflict actually is since there is only one set of messages in the .mc and no messagetable in the .rc.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the only thing I could figure out to get a .rc and an .mc to co-exist was to run mc on the foo.mc file to produce a new foo.rc.  Then in the other .rc file, bar.rc, I used an include on foo.rc.  If such a simple approach works I'm not sure why the build environment can't coordinate this on its own.  But hopefully this helps somebody down the road!